# cuda unavailable in torch with r

Tags: r, gpu, torch

I have used deep learning in the Python environment. Also, i can use keras with gpu in r. But, torch(other deep learning framework in r package)couldn't use gpu. When i google, the CUDA version could make the problem. So i downloaded 10.2v and latest version 11.2v. Then, it get into path.

```
Sys.getenv()
CUDA                                      10.2
CUDA_PATH                                 C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2
CUDA_PATH_V10_0                           C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.0
CUDA_PATH_V10_2                           C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v10.2
CUDA_PATH_V11_2                           C:\Program Files\NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit\CUDA\v11.2
```

But

```
>cuda_is_available()
FALSE
```

How can i fixed return TRUE?

Comment: I have tried latest cuda version , but same.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, second line source code has occurred error code. But just reinstall, you can use gpu in torch with R!

```
Sys.setenv("CUDA_HOME" = "C:/Program Files/NVIDIA GPU Computing Toolkit/CUDA/v10.2") 
source("https://raw.githubusercontent.com/mlverse/torch/master/R/install.R")    
install.packages("torch")
```